# Form with TableLayoutPanel: can't shrink Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` with 4 columns and 3 rows.
First and second row (with span): 4 `GroupBox`es with `TextBox`es and `Labels` in them.
Bottom row: a `GridView` filled by `DataAdapter`

The controls inside the `TableLayoutPanel` are anchored `Top,Bottom,Left,Right`. `AutoSize` is `false`.

Columns are sized with 25%; Rows: First 2 rows with absolute values, last row with 100%.

When I start the program all works fine. When I make the window bigger using the mouse (at the bottom right corner) it works fine! All controls grow dynamically.

But then I can't shrink the Window using the mouse the same way! I see the arrows, but can't shrink.

`AutoSizeMode` of `TableLayoutPanel` is `GrowAndShrink`.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem with screenshots (better with [screen-to-gif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/))? Are you doing anything to layout manually (e.g. handling `Form.Resize` and moving/resizing something)? Consider to prepare and include [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm just new to this site, so i cant put my gif in. Its just simple to explain: Sizing with Mouse in MainForms-Corner (Click and Hold--arrows shown) does only work when size it bigger. Size smaller does not work for the user.

Its all done in Designer, not in Code.

Comment: MCVE still is a good option (or maybe simply posting layout from current `Form.designer.cs`). Right now I can only speculate what not every control (talking about content of `TableLayoutPanel`) has `GrowAndShrink` mode, blocking `Form` size from being reduced.

Comment: This is the kind of problem you get when you waffle over who determines the size of the UI.  Clearly you want the user to be in control, as you should, so you must set the form's AutoSize property back to False.

Comment: great, that was the solution. Now it works fine. Thank you :)